# PHP / MySQL - mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

There are a hundred questions that all relate to this error some how. I've been through every one of them...twice.

I've been working on a pretty robust client management system with PHP and MySQL over the last year and I'm nearing the end. This error pops up every now and then and it DRIVES ME NUTS.

I have three other examples of this code working flawlessly on other parts of my site. I copied and posted it to a new page, changed some variables, and without fail MySQL says to check the quotes and that my version might be wrong. I'm pulling my hair out....please help!

```
// Update existing contact list
if(count($_POST['existing_contact']) > 0){
    foreach ($_POST['existing_contact'] as $exist_contact) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `contact_lists` SET
            contact_lists.sequence = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['sequence'])."' ,
            contact_lists.name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['name'])."' ,
            contact_lists.primary_phone = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['primary_type'])."' ,
            contact_lists.primary_type = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['primary_type'])."' ,
            contact_lists.secondary_phone = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['secondary_phone'])."' ,
            contact_lists.secondary_type = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['secondary_type'])."' ,
            contact_lists.panel_code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['panel_code'])."' ,
            contact_lists.password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['contact_password'])."' 
            WHERE `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_contact['contact_identifier'])."")
            or die(mysql_error("<font size='-1' face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'>Can't connect to MySQL. Please try again.</font>"));
    };
};
```

This is what I get from phpMyAdmin

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence']).&quot;' ,
                                     contact_lists.name = '&quot;.mysql_real_escape_string($ex' at line 2
```

I swear this exact piece of code with different variables is running in two or three other locations throughout my site. If you can see anything out of the ordinary here, please point me in the right cirection. Thanks!

EDIT ------

Here is the original code this was copied and pasted from. (of course, with variable changes)

```
// Update existing zone list
if(count($_POST['existing_zone']) > 0){
    foreach ($_POST['existing_zone'] as $exist_zone) {
        if($exist_zone['zone_exists'] == TRUE) { $zone_exists_checked = "1"; } else { $zone_exists_checked = "0"; };
        mysql_query("UPDATE `zone_lists` SET
                                    zone_lists.zone_number = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_zone['zone_number'])."' ,
                                    zone_lists.zone_description = '".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_zone['zone_description'])."' ,
                                    zone_lists.zone_existing = '".mysql_real_escape_string($zone_exists_checked)."'
                                    WHERE `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($exist_zone['zone_list_identifier'])."")
            or die(mysql_error("<font size='-1' face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'>Can't connect to MySQL. Please try again.</font>"));
    };
};
```

Comment: Since when does phpmyadmin let you run PHP in its query console?

Comment: I take out all the extra stuff and start with UPDATE or whatever the command is I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED.**

Okay, so here's the deal...

Everything was good in the piece of code. As it turns out the variable in the `WHERE` clause was empty because of a single letter typo. I had "conctact" instead of "contact" in the form on the previous page. I started by replacing all of the variables with static information and ran the code each time I reinserted a variable.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) only takes a resource as its argument (one created with `mysql_connect()`). You are trying to supply a string.

What you probably have working elsewhere is:

`or die("<font size='-1' face='Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'>Can't connect to MySQL. Please try again.</font>");`

Comment: I took out the mysql_error but the issue still exists. All that is different now is that it's my generic "Can't connect" message telling me something is wrong instead of the previously posted MySQL error.

Comment: @backyard what about printing the actual mysql_error instead of your generic "Can't connect"?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10`

Comment: Here's a little extra info...

I replaced all of the variables with static information and tried to run it and it was successful. Could this be because of some of the specific data? Data type or something?

Comment: Yes it definitely could be. Its been a loooong time since ive used `ext/mysql` (or `Mysqli` for that matter) though so im probably not the best to weigh in on specifics.